# Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP), Proxy Pattern and Exceptions

Tags: design-patterns, exception, liskov-substitution-principle

Suppose I have an interface and a concrete implementation of it that the client code uses. Now, using the proxy pattern that implements this interface, I could route the requests made to the interface over a network. The network connection can of course fail which might throw an exception.

The client code that uses the interface would then get an unexpected exception. I guess in this situation the LSP principle is violated.

But how would one handle the network exceptions in this case if they are not allowed to propagate out of the interface?

Here some Java code to clarify what I mean:

```
interface Interface
{
    abstract void method1();
    abstract void method2();
    abstract void method3();
}

class Implementation implements Interface
{
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();
}

class ProxyOverNetwork implements Interface
{
    // I can't add the NetworkException as it is not part of the Interface 
    // and would violate LSP, but how to handle the network problems then,
    // when the ProxyOverNetwork might not be the right place to do so?

    void method1() throws(NetworkException);
    void method2() throws(NetworkException);
    void method3() throws(NetworkException);
}
```

Would I have to change the interface to allow exceptions to propagate out?

Comment: Why do you think that a connection failure is a violation of Liskov Substitution Principle? 
Ask yourself how many responsibilities we have here?

Comment: The original interface does not have anything to do with network access so would also not specicy any exceptions thrown, but the proxy implementation which uses the network does.

Comment: I think that the distribution mechanism used as a dependency by the proxy  (behind the scenes) is what confusing you here. You could try abstract it as a dependency to your proxy interface, and things will be clearer then.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're writing in Java, if you want your `Interface` to be implemented in a way such that method calls can fail, you'll need to do one of two things: either

- change `Interface`'s methods so that they raise a checked exception, or
- make the implementations raise unchecked exceptions.

The relative advantages and disadvantages of checked and unchecked exceptions are discussed at length on SO and all over the Internet. I haven't written much Java for a few years, but a few years ago the trend was to use only unchecked exceptions, to save the caller the trouble of handling them. Honest Ruby people (I am one) will tell you that they forget to handle error cases all the time thanks to their untyped language and end up handling them in hotfixes. Haskell is trendy now, a language in which type signatures are used to restrict behavior in ways which would make the unchecked-exceptions camp run screaming for the hills.

I would use a checked exception to ensure the caller handles possible failures. I wouldn't use `NetworkException`, though, but something generic like `MethodFailureException` (if we knew what `Interface` did we could choose a better name) which `NetworkException` could extend. That saves the caller from knowing about the implementation while still allowing them to handle the error.